# Does Ubuntu Support CDMA/LTE on the Sprint Galaxy Nexus

Tags: android, cdma

I'm looking to switch from Android OS to Ubuntu on my Sprint Samsung Galaxy Nexus. I was wondering if Ubuntu supports CDMA and LTE.

Answer (score 1):

Not yet, hopefully in the near future.  See info from release notes here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/ReleaseNotes#Telephony

Also, from: http://www.xda-developers.com/android/ubuntu-touch-next-generation-os-or-just-another-skin/

"Fear Not Sprint and Verizon users, it is being worked on. The Ubuntu Team said that the GSM Radio is the global standard and this was simply where they focused most of their attention as all of the developers had GSM devices. "